# How can I make log4j reopen log files periodically (logrotate)

Tags: log4j, logrotate

My sysadmin has been "encouraging" me to fix our web application logs to play nicely with logrotate.  The problem is that after logrotate works on a file the application stops logging.  Is there a way to configure log4j to reopen log files after this happens?

This comment explains the general problem but doesn't provide a solution for log4j: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6514233/201748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have still to test it, but the `copytruncate` option of logrotate should do.

Comment: Yes this is correct.  When I finally solved the issue I forgot about my SO question.  Our problem was some other bad config that was causing logrotate to ignore rules.